# Why is subprocess.call("""scp foo""") broken?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, os.system

**Success:**

```
>>> scp_cmd = r"sudo scp -i /home/backup/.ssh/id_rsa /opt/backups/*conf backup@a-hostname.local:/opt/backups/"
>>> subprocess.call(scp_cmd, shell=True)
1eadmin1.conf                                                  100%   83KB  83.5KB/s   00:00
1stflr_1.conf                                                  100% 2904     2.8KB/s   00:00
>>> scp_cmd = """sudo scp -i /home/backup/.ssh/id_rsa /opt/backups/*conf backup@a-hostname.local:/opt/backups/"""
>>> os.system(scp_cmd)
1eadmin1.conf                                                  100%   83KB  87.3KB/s   00:00
1stflr_1.conf                                                  100% 2904     3.4KB/s   00:00
```

**Failure:**

```
>>> scp_cmd = r"""sudo scp -i /home/backup/.ssh/id_rsa /opt/backups/*conf backup@a-hostname.local:/opt/backups/"""
>>> subprocess.call(scp_cmd, shell=True)
/opt/backups/*conf: No such file or directory
1
>>> subprocess.call(scp_cmd.split(' '))
/opt/backups/\*conf: No such file or directory
1
>>>
>>> subprocess.call(shlex.split(scp_cmd))
/opt/backups/*conf: No such file or directory
1
```

I'm confused why the triple quotes fail when I use `subprocess.call()`, but pass when I use `os.system()`.  Why is there a difference between `subprocess.call()` and `os.system()` when handling triple quoted strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am pretty certain you are doing something else different; the triple quoting isn't making a difference here at all:

```
>>> a = r"sudo scp -i /home/backup/.ssh/id_rsa /opt/backups/*conf backup@a-hostname.local:/opt/backups/"
>>> b = r"""sudo scp -i /home/backup/.ssh/id_rsa /opt/backups/*conf backup@a-hostname.local:/opt/backups/"""
>>> a == b
True
>>> b
'sudo scp -i /home/backup/.ssh/id_rsa /opt/backups/*conf backup@a-hostname.local:/opt/backups/'
>>> a
'sudo scp -i /home/backup/.ssh/id_rsa /opt/backups/*conf backup@a-hostname.local:/opt/backups/'
```

Using triple quoting is just *one* way to specify a python string literal. How you specified that literal (with or without the `r` raw prefix, with single or triple quotes, using single `'` or double `"` quotes) is not preserved.

Where triple quoting *does* make a difference is when you include a newline:

```
>>> foo = '''
... '''
>>> foo
'\n'
```

But your examples do not include any newlines at all.

Comment: Indeed, in fact, the first 'Success' example can't work at all. It needs either, `shell=True` or the command needs to be split.

Comment: @MikePennington: I find that hard to believe. *Something else* changed too.

Comment: @Rob, you're correct and I fixed that in the question; however, that doesn't change the reality that I'm getting failures when I try to scp with triple quotes

Comment: @MikePennington, either your commands run and/or output is wrong or you found a bug in python. In these cases my experience tells me 99.9% it's the former. Please post an entire (i.e. non-interactive) script that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Yeah... I think this has to do with the shell expansion of the *, not the triple-quoting of the string.

Comment: @MikePennington: I know; the point is that that's the only difference a triple quote makes; it makes it easy to include newlines in your string literal, and it makes it easy to include (single) quote literals. *There is no other difference*, the strings produced are otherwise the same. You are thus barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: If you're so sure that this was a problem with "something else changed", why does `subprocess.call(shlex.split(scp_cmd))` fail?

Comment: @MikePennington: Because I know how python string literals work. You asked if a triple quoted string is different, and I can help you with that: No, there is absolutely *no* difference. That's why I am sure. Without more code from you, I cannot see what else could have changed in the meantime, but the triple quoted string *is not the difference*.

Comment: @MikePennington, that fails because there's no shell-expansion if you run it like that.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to everything Martijn has said, and I think I may know what's going on.  This output:

```
>>> subprocess.call(scp_cmd.split(' '))
/opt/backups/\*conf: No such file or directory
```

looks suspicious to me.  **Why is the backslash there?**

Doing my best to match your command, I get something like [suppressing only the username]:

```
>>> import subprocess, shlex
>>> 
>>> subprocess.call(r"scp -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa /tmp/*conf user@localhost:/tmp/save", shell=True)
aconf                                    100%    4     0.0KB/s   00:00    
bconf                                    100%    9     0.0KB/s   00:00    
0
>>> subprocess.call(r"""scp -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa /tmp/*conf user@localhost:/tmp/save""", shell=True)
aconf                                    100%    4     0.0KB/s   00:00    
bconf                                    100%    9     0.0KB/s   00:00    
0
```

which works because as explained, they're the same string.  But say you had accidentally put a backslash in there?  You'd get

```
>>> subprocess.call(r"""scp -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa /tmp/\*conf user@localhost:/tmp/save""", shell=True)
/tmp/*conf: No such file or directory
1
>>> subprocess.call(r"""scp -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa /tmp/\*conf user@localhost:/tmp/save""".split(" "))
/tmp/\*conf: No such file or directory
1
>>> subprocess.call(shlex.split(r"""scp -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa /tmp/\*conf user@localhost:/tmp/save"""))
/tmp/*conf: No such file or directory
1
```

which matches your output exactly -- there's no backslash in the output for `shell=True` or `shlex.split()`, but there is for `.split(" ")`.  For comparison, if there were no backslash, you should instead get the error message

```
>>> subprocess.call(r"""scp -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa /tmp/*conf user@localhost:/tmp/save""".split(" "))
/tmp/*conf: No such file or directory
1
```

So it seems to me very likely that the `scp_cmd` you've posted isn't the one your output actually corresponds to, and that your real one has a backslash.

Comment: of course, when you're troubleshooting something for 20 minutes, it doesn't make sense to post all 20 minutes of debugging in the question... yes I experimented with a backslash escape on the *, no that didn't cause the problem

Comment: @MikePennington: respectfully, I don't see how the `scp_cmd` you posted, which does not contain a backslash, is compatible with the output you posted, which does.  I have demonstrated above a prima facie case that inserting one generates your output and not inserting one does not.

Comment: You have demonstrated that the question doesn't reflect every single case I tested, and that I hacked the question together imperfectly. For that I apologize... regardless, your conclusion is flawed.  The original script which also had the error never had a backslash.